# Dynamic Component Click Event Binding Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

In my project I'm loading some elements dynamically.But I'm not able to generate click events for that elements.

```
import {Component, DynamicComponentLoader, Injector} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
  <button (click)="form()">
    View Form
  </button>
    <div id="form" [innerHTML]="">
      Welcome..! Here form component will be loaded.

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
    private strForMarkets = "";
    private sbForMarkets: Array<string> = [];
  constructor(public dcl:DynamicComponentLoader, public _injector:Injector) {
  }
  form() {
      var s = ["a", "s", "d", "p"];
      this.sbForMarkets.push("<div><ul>")
      for (var index = 0; index < s.length; index++) {
          var element = s[index];
          this.sbForMarkets.push("<li class='OH liDataLeftFilterMarketsContainer'>");
          this.sbForMarkets.push("<div class='FL sprite_icon expand-icon-market'></div>");
          this.sbForMarkets.push("<div class='expand-text-div CP FT14 LH15' (click)='chill($event)' >" + element + "</div>");
          this.sbForMarkets.push("</li>");
      }
      this.sbForMarkets.push("</ul></div>");
      this.strForMarkets = this.sbForMarkets.join("");
  }

  chill() {
      console.log("Dude... Chill  ");
    }
}
```

p.s. I have tried with dynamic component loader but it works if all html in template only.

Comment: Where are you adding it? How does the `this.dcl.loadXxx()` code look like? `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` instead. For an example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular2 doesn't process HTML added dynamically using `[innerHTML]="..."` or similar in any way `(click)` is just ignored and added as-is.

If possible wrap the HTML in a component and use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` instead. For an example see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: Thanks. And I have another doubt in that example you have separate components for the data you have. My data is coming from database. So I cannot have components right?

Comment: Do you mean content like `FT14 LH15`? You can use Angular binding to add it to the DOM like `{{someProp}}` or `*ngFor` to generate HTML from data. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: I don't know what FT14 and LH15 mean but that link can solve my problems.

Comment: The link shows how to add components dynamically but the HTML of the contents is static but supports binding like `[]` and {{}}`.